# intellitest- Could not generate any test in x runs

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automated-tests, pex, intellitest

I Could not generate test cases by using intellitest. After fixing issues i always come to point where i got warning that "Could not generate any test in x runs".Is there any manual step i need to follow? or this warning comes due to bad code or may be any limitations by intellitest framework.

Any ideas please ? I've been trying for the last many days :/

I am having a class named "HolidaySetupComponent". I want to create test cases for this class method "GetEmailContent(string emailtypeTag)".

Below is my code.

```
public class HolidaySetupComponent
{
    private string table1;
    private string table2;
    private string table3;
    public String _CompanyId;
     int _CompId;

    string connectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HCMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    DataServices dataservice = new DataServices();

    public HolidaySetupComponent()
    {
        dataservice.BeginProcess(connectionString);
        table1 = "tblHoliday";
        table2 = "tblSetupsDetail";
        table3 = "tblEmailHistory";
        _CompanyId = Utilities.GetCompanyId();
    }
    public DataSet GetEmailContent(string emailtypeTag)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int emailtypetagId = 0;
        if (emailtypeTag == "NationalTab")
        {
            emailtypetagId = 4;
        }
        else { emailtypetagId = 5; }
        string whereclause = "EmailType  = " + emailtypetagId + "AND CompanyId =" + Utilities.GetCompanyId();
        string result = dataservice.GetDataWithClause("*", "tblEmailContentCreation", whereclause, ref ds);

        return ds;
    }
}

public static class Utilities
{
    static DataServices dataService = new DataServices();
    static DataServices dataServiceAuditTrail = new DataServices();

    public Utilities()
    {
        dataService.BeginProcess(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HCMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        dataServiceAuditTrail.BeginProcess(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vCurioAuditTrailConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public static String GetCompanyId()
    {
    var _clientIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues("login");
    string prefix = Utilities.GetPrefix(_clientIP[0]);
    string _loginDetail = Utilities.GetKeyInRedis(prefix + "OtherData");
    DataTable dtloginDetail = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_loginDetail, (typeof(DataTable)));
    String _CompanyId = String.Empty;
    if (dtloginDetail != null && dtloginDetail.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        DataRow drloginDetail = dtloginDetail.Rows[0];
        _CompanyId = drloginDetail["CompanyId"].ToString();
    }

    return _CompanyId;
    }
}
```

When i click on "Run intellitest" on "GetEmailContent(string emailtypeTag)" method exist in "holidaySetupComponent" i got following warnings.

[warnings snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fel1.png)

At this step as i understand that i need to fix this warning so I selected all warnings under these options and apply fix.

- Object Creation (2)
- Uninstrumented Method (4)

"Fix" option was disabled for remaing warnings under below warning so i "Supperss"  these warnings

- Runtime Warning
- Static Field Store

After applying these fixes intellitest created a factory class "HolidaySetupComponentFactory" for object creation of "HolidaySetupComponent"

```
public static partial class HolidaySetupComponentFactory
{
    ///<summary>A factory for HolidaySetupComponent instances</summary>
    [PexFactoryMethod(typeof(global::HolidaySetupComponent))]
    public static global::HolidaySetupComponent Create(string _CompanyId_s)
    {
    global::HolidaySetupComponent holidaySetupComponent
       = new global::HolidaySetupComponent();
    holidaySetupComponent._CompanyId = _CompanyId_s;
    return holidaySetupComponent;

    // TODO: Edit factory method of HolidaySetupComponent
    // This method should be able to configure the object in all possible ways.
    // Add as many parameters as needed,
    // and assign their values to each field by using the API.
    }
}
```

and also added these lines in PexAssemblyInfo.cs by intellitest when i "suppress" warnings.

```
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Configuration")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentType(typeof(Attribute))]
[assembly: PexInstrumentType(typeof(TextReader))]
[assembly: PexSuppressStaticFieldStore("System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider", "_intrinsicTypeConverters")]
[assembly: PexSuppressStaticFieldStore(typeof(AttributeCollection), "_defaultAttributes")]
[assembly: PexSuppressStaticFieldStore("System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider", "_attributeCache")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Xml")]
[assembly: PexSuppressExplorableEvent(typeof(global::HolidaySetupComponent))]
```

After this i get "Runtime Warning" that i cannot rid off

[Final Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpqTn.png)

Need Help!!!

Thanks

Comment: I have also followed this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521004/White-box-testing-with-PEX%22) post but it didn't helped